# Are there is vanadium-free high speed steels?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, structural-engineering, materials, steel, metallurgy

Vanadium is present in all high speed steel grades. Unfortunately vanadium is not only very expensive but is also a well known cytotoxic metal. Some workers get a severe persistent cough lasting for months for from contact with dust or vapors containing vanadium which are present in a workshop!

I searched a lot but can not find any high speed steels without vanadium,  except some research grades which replaced vanadium by niobium but unfortunately niobium forms very coarse carbides which are very detrimental to steel toughness.

My question is do vanadium-free high speed steels or any temper-resisting steels with similar hardness exist?

Comment: Are these workers using Vanadium to *make* the steel or are they using V-steel tools?  The source of cough is not clear here.

Comment: they using ferrovanadium to make steel . 
grinding or machining of tool steel can lead to contact with vanadium containing dust , even if the vanadium content in the steel is just 1% it is better to stay away from it .

Comment: Have you tried local fume/dust extractors? They would probably be the easier than changing to a new material.

Answer (score 0):

No. Surprisingly ( to me) it is in every high speed steel. It forms a very hard ,very stable carbide , VC. This carbide does not even dissolve during the normal very high temperature austenize heat.  So people must actually allergic to VC , as there is no available V. It has been used in essentially all HSS since 1910 . Makes me wonder why this problem was unknown until now . ( ASM Tool Steel handbook , 1962.)

Comment: I read a book named "tool steels:5th Edition" and it mentioned some hot work steels free from vanadium and they have just a 1-2 Rc lower hardness and red hardness compared to vanadium-containing steels . but it did not mention any vanadium-free high speed steel though that slight reduction in red hardness is acceptable.

Comment: Hot work tool steel is not "high speed steel"  : There are many categories of tool steels . If you believe the story about V , pick a steel with no V ' it just won't be high speed steel.

Comment: hot work steels are very similar to high speed steels , not only in retaining hardness in high temperatures but some hot work steels are a low carbon version of high speed steel. like H26 grade which is actually a lower carbon grade of T1 steel.

Comment: Interesting that you pick the only tungsten hot work steel that contains V, apparently. Grades H 20 to H 25  should not contain V. Although not HSS they are similar and may meet your requirements.